# Dynamic File Upload using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

In the below code i have a dynamic file upload i have to upload multiple files using ajax.I tried the below code but the request file count is 0.Please help me to overcome this issue.

```
 <input id="Button1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add Files" onclick = "AddFileUpload()" />

 function AddFileUpload() {

            var div = document.createElement('DIV');
            div.innerHTML = '<input id="file' + counter + '" multiple  name = "file' + counter +
                     '" type="file" />' +
                     '<input id="Button' + counter + '" type="button" ' +
                     'value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveFileUpload(this)" />' + '<input id="BtnUpld' + counter + '" value="Upload"  name = "BtnUpld' + counter +
                     '" onclick = "Upload()" type="Button" />';
            document.getElementById("FileUploadContainer").appendChild(div);
            counter++;

        }




function Upload() {
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "NewTask.aspx/Upload",
                data: '',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {

                }
            });

<div id = "FileUploadContainer">

</div>



[WebMethod]
        public static void Upload()
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: you are not passing the file anywhere? Show some `html` too to understand your `DOM` structure.. Where you are calling this `AddFileUpload` function.. Is there any `form` involved?

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You have to attach the file somewhere

You have 2 options:

1. Send it via `AJAX` and `base64` format (or using `FormData` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects - **it's not cross platform**).
2. Send it using regular `Form` like this answer(http://forums.asp.net/t/1569041.aspx?add+dynamically+fileupload+control+#3928265, I can't post the full code here)